# the Chi-squared distribution and Mahalanobis

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, chi-squared-distribution, mahalanobis

I'm doing some simulations in C++ and OpenGL (2D and 3D) for navigating a robot in unknown environment known as SLAM. I'm using Extended Kalman filter as an optimal estimator. In SLAM problem, once the robot detects a beacon (aka landmark or feature) in based-feature map, the robot must decide whether this beacon has been observed before or it is a new landmark. The most common approach for solving this problem is by using The Nearest Neighbor Standard Filter (NNSF). In this method, we first generate an predicted measurement to a landmark and compare it with the observed measurement that is coming from the sensor. Based on this comparison, we decide whether the predicted and observed measurement indeed belong to a specific landmark.   All papers I've read refer readers for this book [Tracking and Data Association](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120797607), a very well known book in this field for more information about NNSF. Basically they use [the Mahalanobis distance](http://journals1.scholarsportal.info/details/01697439/v50i0001/1_tmd.xml) which is

$$
(z^{i} - \hat{z}^{j})^{T}S^{-1}(z^{i} - \hat{z}^{j}) \leq \chi^{2}_{k,\alpha}
$$
 where $(z^{i} - \hat{z}^{j})$ is the innovation (i.e. the difference between the observed and the predicted measurements), $S$ is the innovation covariance, $k$ is degree of freedom, and $\alpha$ is the confidence level. For short,

$$
d^{2} \leq \gamma
$$

where $d^{2}$ is the squared Mahalanobis distance and $\gamma$ is the threshold of the validation gate.Unfortunately all papers that I've read state that this value $\chi^{2}$ can be obtained from the chi-square distribution with some confidence in our measurements and how accurate our sensors with no further information regarding this matter which makes me wonder if this is a basic stuff in statistics and object recognition.  My question is how can I choose this value? Since I'm doing simulation, I know the uncertainty of my sensors. How can I determine the confidence level from my sensor noise (i.e. $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2})$)? Every time I choose a sensible value, the filter fails to decide whether the observed measurements belong to  existing landmarks which leads to the divergence of EKF. This is because every time the robot observes a landmark, the robot adds it to its state vector.
 This is what I've done to determine the threshold $\gamma$. Since I have $k = 2$ and I will assume some confidence level $\alpha = 0.05$, so from the chi-square table, I get

$$
\chi^{2}_{2,0.05} = 5.991
$$

Comment: Why only two degrees of freedom?  Do you only have 2D measurements?  How have you selected $S$?

Comment: @AndrewM, yes I do. I will update the question about $S$.